# IRS AIR 1095B Manifest Schema -- OriginalReceiptID

Tags: irs

I'm attempting to upload AIR test 2C via the IRS UI web portal and received the following submission error: "The manifest file does not match our current schema.  In particular, our system has detected a potential issue with the following element(s)" OriginalReceiptID

Here's our manifest file:

[top portion of our manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfDEa.jpg)

Can anyone find the errors of my ways?

Comment: Please [edit] and post the text of your actual code, not a screenshot.

Comment: "OriginalReceiptID" should be spelled as OriginalReceiptId.  Evidently, the IRS doesn't have a sense of humor

Answer (score 1):

- You need to provide the `OriginalReceiptId` (on the Manifest) only when sending a **Replacement** record type for a previously "Rejected" *Transmission*.
- The `OriginalUniqueSubmissionId` (on the 1094-C) should be provided only when sending a **Replacement** record type for a previously "Rejected" *Submission*.

**Note:** You will receive Transmission-level error if you include both the `OriginalReceiptId` and `OriginalUniqueSubmissionId`.  The type of rejection dictates which one is needed to be used.  The Type of Rejection is caused by either the Transmission or Submission, and is defined by the reason for the rejection and the structure of the Error Data File received from the status response.

- `CorrectedUniqueSubmissionId` on the 1094-C is used when sending a
  **Correction** record type for a previously "Accepted" or "Accepted with Errors" 1094-C record.
- `CorrectedUniqueRecordId` on the 1095-C is used when sending a
  **Correction** record type for a previously "Accepted" or "Accepted with Errors" 1095-C record.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need  original receipt id for the correction files, it is for rejected files. refer to IRS air composition referece guide at https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p5165.pdf

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation to help this answer?